# How to configure GitLab CI Pipeline only on merge requests and that too only for specific branches?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have following configuration for enabling pipeline on merge requests. I want this pipeline to run only on merge request to few specific branches only.
For Ex: "release/some-xyz-branch"  and "develop" branches.
How to do it ?

```
test_job:
    stage: test
    only:
        - merge_requests
    script:
        - npm run test
```

I have tried adding the branch name after "- merge_requests" as follows but it is not working as expected.

```
test_job:
    stage: test
    only:
        - merge_requests
        - develop
        - release/some-xyz-branch
    script:
        - npm run test
```

Comment: Can i use '&&' operator and write it like, "merge_requests && develop && release/some-xyz-branch" ?

Answer (score 14):

You can use `variables` along with `refs` to run the pipeline.

```
test_async:
  script:
    - echo "Test Async"
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
    variables:
      - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^release\/.*$/

test_db:
  script:
    - echo "Test db"
  only: 
    - master
```

In above yaml, `test_async` will only run when merge request is created and the target branch is either `develop` or starts with `release/`. `test_db` will only run when commited to master.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME** predefined environment variable in combination with **only:variables** to accomplish this behavior

```
test_job:
    stage: test
    only: [merge_requests]
    except:
      variables:
         - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^docs-/
    script:
        - npm run test
```

*Note: docs- represents refs/merge-requests/:iid/head*